# Recursive method to search through folder tree and find specific file types

Tags: java, recursion, directory, subdirectory

So I am writing a code that locates certain information on Protein databases. I know that a recursive folder search is the best possible way to locate these files, but I am very new to this language and have been told to write in Java (I normally do C++)

SO this being said, what method would i use to:

First: Locate the folder on desktop
Second: Open each folder and that folders subfolders
Third: Locate files that end with the ".dat" type (because these are the only files that have stored the Protein information

Thanks for any and all help you can provide

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: only available in 1.7, not everybody is there yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) is *"An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames"*
2. [File.listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) provides a listing of all the files contained within the directory (if the `File` object represents a directory)
3. [File.listFiles(FileFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) provides you with the ability to filter a file list based on your needs

So, with that information...

You would specify a path location with something like...

```
File parent = new File("C:/path/to/where/you/want");
```

You can check that the `File` is a directory with...

```
if (parent.isDirectory()) {
    // Take action of the directory
}
```

You can list the contents of the directory by...

```
File[] children = parent.listFiles();
// This will return null if the path does not exist it is not a directory...
```

You can filter the list in a similar way...

```
File[] children = parent.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            return file.isDirectory() || file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".dat");
        }
    });
// This will return all the files that are directories or whose file name ends
// with ".dat" (*.dat)
```

Other useful methods would include (but not limited to)

- [`File.exists`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) to test that the file actually exists
- [`File.isFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29), basically instead of saying `!File.isDirectory()`
- [`File.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName()), returns the name of the file, excluding it's path
- [`File.getPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getPath()) returns the path and name of the file.  This can be relative, so be careful, see [`File.getAbsolutePath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsolutePath()) and [`File.getCanonicalPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getCanonicalPath()) to resolve this.
- [`File.getParentFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile()) which gives you access to the parent folder

Comment: nice explained and structured!

Answer (score 8):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
public static void searchForDatFiles(File root, List<File> datOnly) {
    if(root == null || datOnly == null) return; //just for safety   
    if(root.isDirectory()) {
        for(File file : root.listFiles()) {
            searchForDatFiles(file, datOnly);
        }
    } else if(root.isFile() && root.getName().endsWith(".dat")) {
        datOnly.add(root);
    }
}
```

After this method returns, the `List<File>` passed to it will be filled with the .dat files of your directory, and all subdirectories (if i'm not mistaken).

Comment: This is great. Very clean and easy. So once I have implemented this I will need to run the ".dat" through a method that runs the String through a loop that checks it for certain data and then puts that data into another class i called Protein. So in the 
else if(root.isFile() && root.getName().endsWith(".dat"))

what would i have to add in that to call the other method on the .dat

Comment: also will this check the entire tree for ALL .dat?

Comment: yes it will process all the .dat-s. If you want to collect them, pass add a collection as parameter (List for example), and add the file to it in the `else if` branch

Comment: Is the `root.isFile()` part really necessary in the `else` section? I might be forgetting something important here, but, by entering the `else` section, which is a result of the file not being a folder, didn't you inherently already establish that the file is a file?

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the Java `File` APIs. In particular you should look at the [listFiles method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) and write `FileFilter` that selects directories and, of course, the files you're interested into.

A method that will return you all the files matching your criteria (Given that you implement the `FileFilter`) is this:

```
List<File> searchForFile(File rootDirectory, FileFilter filter){
    List<File> results = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File currentItem : rootDirectory.listFiles(filter){
      if(currentItem.isDirectory()){
          results.addAll(searchForFile(currentItem), filter)
      }
      else{
          results.add(currentItem);
      }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use recursive foldr search and use function endsWith() to find the .bat file then you can use any String function to locate your requires information.