# Android: How to check if a file exists on my sdcard

Tags: java, android, testing

I'm trying to check if a file exists on my sdcard with this code but I have some problems. The API version on my Android phone is 19 and the API version of the application is 19 but there are a lot of exceptions from other application which I do not want to work with like zedge for example. Please give me some hints on how to check if that file exists.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");

    if(myFile.exists()){
        Log.d("File", "exists");
    }

}


public boolean isExternalStorage() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

My Manifest file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: you will find a lot of links with same problem along with their solutions

Comment: Your question is too vague. You are already checking if a file exists. What do you mean by "exceptions from other application"?

Answer (score 0):

your code just checks if file exists at sdcard/fileName.ext :

```
File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/test.txt");

    if(myFile.exists()){
        Log.d("File", "exists");
    }
```

To search entire file system (dir tree), we need a recursive function which enters a directory or compares a file with search file name:

```
public static boolean searchForFile(File root, File mySearchFile)
{
    if(root == null || mySearchFile == null) return; //just for safety   

    if(root.isDirectory())
    {
        Boolean flag = false;
        for(File file : root.listFiles()){
            flag = searchForDatFiles(file, mySearchFile);
            if(flag) return true;
       }
    }
    else if(root.isFile() && root.getName().equals(mySearchFile.getName())
    {
        return true;
    }
 return false;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just saw that you are looking for the file in root folder only. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656569/recursive-method-to-search-through-folder-tree-and-find-specific-file-types) link for four ways to check if file exists. Also, above code will work for sdcard only too, but not recommended because it will parse any folders it first encounter. Good for whole directory tree search.

Comment: OK but now i`m trying to check if this file exists it the hard coded path because later i will try to encrypt it. I do not need to searcg the entrire system for the file with the given name.