# Java - Moving files within filesystem

Tags: java, io, filesystems

I am working on school assignment and we are doing simple filemanager that should move all files with suffix `"jpg"` (for example) into another folder. Problem is that we should do it recursively through all the folders.

Example: you are in folder "downloads":

```
--downloads
----me.jpg
----smth.doc
----folder1
------you.jpg
```

and now you have to move all .jpg files into folder "photos" and create "folder1" there and also move file "you.jpg"

This is what I have but it seems to move only files from "downloads folder"

```
private void move(String suffix, String sourcePath, String destination) throws IOException{
    File dir = new File(sourcePath);
    File destDir = new File(destination);
    String src;
    String dst;

    for (File f : dir.listFiles(new ExtensionFilter(suffix))){
        String name = f.getName();
        src = f.getAbsolutePath();
        dst = destination + "\\" + name;
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(destination));
        Files.move(Paths.get(src), Paths.get(dst));
        logs.add("MV;" + src + ";" + dst);
    }

    for (File f : dir.listFiles(new DirectoryFilter())){
        move(suffix, f.getPath(), destination + "\\" + f.getName());    
    }
}
```

logs is just ArrayList to save log which files have been moved

Comment: Start by having a look at [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and [Finding Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html) or, if you're not allowed to use those methods, you could also have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656569/recursive-method-to-search-through-folder-tree-and-find-specific-file-types/12656594#12656594) which uses the `File` API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a lot easier to do using [Java NIO.2 API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) in combination with Java 8.

Java 8 introduced the method [`Files.walk(path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walk-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-) that returns a Stream of all the paths under a given path, recursively:

> Return a `Stream` that is lazily populated with `Path` by walking the file tree rooted at a given starting file.

A proposed solution could then be the following:

```
private void move(String suffix, Path source, Path destination) throws IOException {
    Files.createDirectories(destination);
    Files.walk(source)
         .filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(suffix))
         .forEach(p -> {
             Path dest = destination.resolve(source.relativize(p));
             try {
                 Files.createDirectories(dest.getParent());
                 Files.move(p, dest);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
             }
         });
}
```

This code creates the destination path. Then it walks starting from the source path and filters only the paths that ends with the given suffix. Finally, for each of them:

- [`source.relativize(p)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize-java.nio.file.Path-) returns the relative path from the source to this path.

  > For example, on UNIX, if this path is "/a/b" and the given path is "/a/b/c/d" then the resulting relative path would be "c/d".

  As such, this will return the part of the path under the source so that we can copy it into the target path.
- [`destination.resolve(other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve-java.nio.file.Path-) returns the path constructed by appending this path to the other path:

  > In the simplest case, [...], in which case this method *joins* the given path to this path and returns a resulting path that ends with the given path.
- So now, we effectively have the full target path. We first need to create the parent directories with [`Files.createDirectories(dir)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-). [`dest.getParent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getParent--) returns the parent path, that is to say, it drops the filename from the path. The final step is moving the source path to the target path with [`Files.move(source, target)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

---

If you can't upgrade to Java 8 yet and keep with Java 7, you can still use [`Files.walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) instead of `Files.walk` (the rest of the code would need adjustment but the idea is the same).

Comment: For posterity I'd just like to point out that the result of `Files.walk` needs to be used in a try-with-resources block.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) from Apache Commons IO. That's the easiest way.

Comment: Let's assume for a moment, that since this is school assignment, they are discouraged from using 3rd party libraries and would encouraged to use the basic Java libaries