# How to check if the folder exists in subfolder of same level in java?

Tags: java

I have folder structure as below and I need to check and copy files from AB1 folder to CD1 folder.

```
Root Folder
|___AB ------------------------>DD
    |__AB1 and AB2(folders)      |_AB1 and AB2
        |_CD1                       |__CD1 |__CD2
```

But it is checking for CD1 in both AB1 and AB2 folders and
files are not generating.

```
File file = new File("workspace");
List<File> abFolders = getDir(file); //level 1 folders
abFolders = new ArrayList<File>(abFolders);
List<File> cdFolders = getSubdirs(abFolders); //level 2 folders

//print
for (File file1 : abFolders) {
    for(File file2:cdFolders){
     //Here I need to check if CD folder is present in AB1 then it has to copy to CD1 and not to check for another CD1 folder in AB2 folder.
         System.out.println(file1.getName());
         System.out.println(file2.getName());
    }
    
}

private static List<File> getDir(File file) {
    List<File> subdirs = Arrays.asList(file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            return f.isDirectory();
        }
    }));
    return subdirs;
}
static List<File> getSubdirs(List<File> subdirs) {
    List<File> deepSubdirs = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(File subdir : subdirs) {
        deepSubdirs.addAll(getDir(subdir)); 
    }
    //subdirs.addAll(deepSubdirs);
    return deepSubdirs;
}
```

Comment: Is CD1 folder, INSIDE the AB1 folder?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos yes CD1 Folder is inside of AB1 Folder

Comment: So you want to transfer, all neighbor folders of CD1, inside CD1?

Comment: Now it is selecting the folders like first AB2 and checking for CD1 and if it is not present code stops there....and it wasn't checking for AB1 of CD1 folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive method to search through folder tree and find specific file types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656569/recursive-method-to-search-through-folder-tree-and-find-specific-file-types)

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos not a folder i was merging the files of same name from both folders and generating the file like `Example:if AB1 has 1.txt and CD1 has 1.txt...i was merging those two and generating the file with the name as 1-AB1-CD1.txt `

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos While merging the files i am getting the issue of selecting the folders and its subfolders.

Comment: So, the system is only checking inside AB2?

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos yes it is stoping at inside AB2 and not checking for AB1 -->CD1

Comment: Wait, so it checks AB1, AB2, but it does not check CD1, right?

Comment: Like...I am not getting an idea to write a condition to move to another folder  like from AB1 to AB2 using f2.getName()...I am getting as AB2 and AB1  and after completion of AB2 only it is checking for AB1...if nothing exists in AB2 it stops there and it terminates

Comment: So, it does not even check AB1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219731/discussion-between-l-papadopoulos-and-yadi).

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos Wait, so it checks AB1, AB2, but it does not check CD1, right?
Answer is yes....But I need if nothing is present in AB2.. it has to go and check for AB1and CD1...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use collections, so that you sort  abFolders and cdFolders. First import the library:

```java
import java.util.Collections;
```

Then do the sort of AB folders, before entering loop.

```java
Collections.sort(abFolders);
for (File file1 : abFolders) {
    for(File file2:cdFolders){
     //Here I need to check if CD folder is present in AB1 then it has to copy to CD1 and not to check for another CD1 folder in AB2 folder.
         System.out.println(file1.getName());
         System.out.println(file2.getName());
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Ok I will check it. But why dont you ask a new question for that problem? That way, more people (and maybe more experts) will be able to answer.

Comment: i was not able to add the question it is saying like ....you were not able to ask the question for longer time'

Comment: I know, I will check it